# Python Regex to exclude the email domain and special character and extract @user in the twitter

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I have a string twitter text  as following:

```
str = "RT@aquage_7: 田@tianke おっ(´・ω・｀) @_@, ＠__田科,
 my email is tian@gmail.com, his@kate, I like @lucyさん, 
 and her email is kate@163.cn".
```

The regex pattern is:

```
p_name3 = re.compile(r'[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})')
```

But the result is:

```
 ['aquage_7', 'tianke', '_', '__', 'gmail', 'kate', 'lucy', '163']
```

I hope the result is:

```
 ['aquage_7', 'tianke', '__', 'kate', 'lucy']
```

I mean I want to exclude the email domain name(please don't just focus on these two email domains) and special characters such as:

@_@,   @____@.

In addition, you should know that the twitter user name include: a-zA-Z0-9_ and total character number is between 1 and 15. please give me your hand to solve this issue and trouble me for serval days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not so simple, as it is pretty much entirely contextual. What should happen with a tweet like: `RT@gmail.can you fix the bug in my inbox though?`, where the user is retweeting a tweet from [@gmail](https://twitter.com/gmail) and happens to forget to put a space after the period? From the regex's perspective, `gmail` could equally be a valid user or the domain of the email address `RT@gmail.can`.

Comment: For the record, do you know that twitter's API can directly return the @mentions, without having to parse them ?

Comment: thanks for your comments@3kt, what's meaning of the " twitter's API can directly return the @mentions", do you have documents or links about this? thanks!

Comment: @tktktk0711you can take a look at [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets). The returned JSON has a field called `user_mentions`.

Comment: do you know how to use it, for about this example, I am ke@tom, and @tianさん. I am new to twitter API

Comment: Try [`r'[@＠](?!_+@|\S*\.(?:com|org|cn|MORE_COMMON_TLDs)\b)([A-Z0-9_]{1,15})'`](https://regex101.com/r/yN6hU2/1). Add more TLDs to make sure you disallow emails only - however, that will hardly be perfect. It might be good-enough though.

Comment: thanks@ Wiktor Stribiżew , you are a kind guy. but what about this@galaxy5univbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb. this is not user, but using you pattern, the@galaxy5univbbbb will be extracted, actually, this is not user

Comment: @tktktk0711: You got the gist. Add more restrictions as you need on the go. And remember regex is no magic or panaceum. I do not want to answer since there is no correct regex answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the twitter API if you can. But if you are looking for a simple string solution, break the problem into two steps. First, locate and remove any likely email addresses, then use your regex to find twitter @mentions.

Adapting the first email matching regex from [How to Find or Validate an Email Address](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) to Python looks like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b')
```

(Yes, matching email addresses with a regex is fraught, but it may still give you useful results.) Applying it to your string,

```
>>> s = """RT@aquage_7: @tianke おっ(´・ω・｀) @_@, ＠__田科,
my email is tian@gmail.com, his@kate, I like @lucyさん, 
and her email is kate@163.cn"""
```

results in

```
>>> regex.findall(s)
['tian@gmail.com', 'kate@163.cn']
```

Now that you've located the email-like parts, use `re.sub` to remove them.

```
>>> s = email_regex.sub('', s)
```

Then use your original regex to find twitter mentions.

```
>>> mention_regex = re.compile(r'[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,14})')
>>> print(mention_regex.findall(s))
['aquage_7', 'tianke', '_', '__', 'kate', 'lucy']
```

You didn't want to find the `'_'` in `@_@`, however your regex does match that, so refine your regex if necessary.

Comment: Thanks@David,  you are a  kind guy, if there is method to solve it by one step is the best.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the native Twitter's API user mentions parsing (using [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)) :

```
import tweepy

consumer_key='put_key_here'
consumer_secret='put_secret_here'
access_token='put_key_here'
access_token_secret='put_secret_here'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

result = api.search(q='from:CNN', count=1, include_entities=True)

print(result[0].text)
print(result[0].entities)
```

This outputs the tweet itself :

```
RT @cnnbrk: Polls open in historic UK referendum; voters to decide if Britain stays in EU or becomes first country to exit bloc. https://t.…
```

And the entities (mentions, hashtags, urls, etc...), which I pretty-printed here for better understanding:

```
{
    "symbols": [], 
    "user_mentions": [
        {
        "indices": [
            3, 
            10
        ], 
        "screen_name": "cnnbrk", 
        "id": 428333, 
        "name": "CNN Breaking News", 
        "id_str": "428333"
        }
    ], 
    "hashtags": [], 
    "urls": [
        {
        "url": "[url_here]", 
        "indices": [
            139, 
            140
        ], 
        "expanded_url": "[url_here]", 
        "display_url": "[url_here]"
        }
    ]
}
```

In your case, the interesting part is the `user_mentions` array in the JSON.

Comment: thanks for your answers! it may trouble or be impolite to you. If I don't want to use the user_mention to get the name, and I want to parse the name by Regex.how to solve it.

Comment: As stated by @pzp in the comments of your question, it is definitely tricky, and I don't think you can be 100% sure to get the mention in every case. I would highly recommend using existing tools to recover them...